# Criar página estática de página PHP com query mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, htaccess, cache

Meu projeto tem uma página .php que exibe listas de diversas categorias de produtos, a página recebe o ID da categoria e lista os produtos, mas cada ID tem mais de 1mil resultados, e o carregamento da página está pesada, pensei em converter a página em estática assim carregará rapidamente, tente fazer com o .htaccess mas a página continua fazendo a requisição no banco de dados e não tive sucesso.

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"

# CSS / jScript - 5 dias e 2 horas
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 5 days"
```

Alguém tem dica de como converter minhas páginas em estáticas sem que elas não desobedeçam as regras do mod_rewrite ?

Li na internet sobre o [XCache](https://xcache.lighttpd.net/), mas não tenho total liberdade no servidor para instalar e configurar o domínio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução encontrada foi simples, como quero que apenas o conteúdo da DIV seja estático, criei um diretório 'cache' para os arquivos HTML's que serão gerados e armazenados, e posteriormente cada página será verificada no diretório se a mesma existe, se existe, inclui ela no PHP, senão, faz a consulta no mySQL e cria um novo HTML e grava o conteúdo da DIV para uso posterior.

```
<?php
    if(file_exists('cache/'.$idPagina.'.html')) {
        $content = file_get_contents('cache/'.$idPagina.'.html');
        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
        echo $content;
    } else {
        echo "<div class='divCategorias'>";
        $sql = "SELECT ....";
        while(.......);
        echo "</div>";
        //libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTMLFile(site_url_full());
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $element = $xpath->query('//div[@class="divCategorias"]')->item(0);
        $html = $dom->saveHTML($element);
        $data = iconv("CP1257","UTF-8", $data);
        file_put_contents('cache/'.$idPagina.'.html', $html);
        $html = "";
    }
?>
```

Entendimento:
- Se o arquivo HTML em cache existe, imprime ele no PHP.
- Se o arquivo HTML não existe, faz a consulta no DB e depois gera o cache HTML para uso posterior.